# Polymorphic React Component in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to write a code for a polymorphic React component but I'm getting an error on the last line where I'm defining an `onClick` callback for the `<Button />` component.

When I hover over the `onClick` property TS correctly says the type is `(property) onClick?: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> | undefined`, nevertheless I'm still seeing the error `Parameter 'e' implicitly has an 'any' type.(7006).

```
import React from "react";

type ButtonOwnProps<E extends React.ElementType> = {
  as?: E;
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

type ButtonProps<E extends React.ElementType> = ButtonOwnProps<E> &
  Omit<React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<E>, keyof ButtonOwnProps<E>>;

export function Button<E extends React.ElementType = "button">({
  children,
  as,
  ...rest
}: ButtonProps<E>) {
  const Tag = as || "button";

  return (
    <Tag {...rest}>
      {children}
    </Tag>
  );
}

// Parameter 'e' implicitly has an 'any' type.(7006)
//               v                 
<Button onClick={e => console.log(e)}>Click me</Button>
```

[Here](https://shorturl.at/mxAEN) is an interactive TypeScript playground with the above code.

Comment: The TypeScript error you're encountering (Parameter 'e' implicitly has an 'any' type.(7006)) is because TypeScript is inferring the type of the event (e) to be any implicitly, which is generally not recommended because it weakens the type safety TypeScript provides.

Comment: I believe the question is "why isn't the type `MouseEvent | undefined`?", although the OP could be more explicit about that question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey The `React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>` is actually correct.

Comment: @softghost yeah, but it shouldn't be inferring the `e` as any because it already knows what type `e` is. It shouldn't give any error and correctly type the `e` param, same as if you do just this `<button onClick={e => e}>Click me</button>` in which case it works ok.

Answer (score -1):

```
<Button onClick={(e: any) => console.log(e)}>Click me</Button>
```

If you explicitly specify the type of e as any, TypeScript won't raise an error, but it also means you're opting out of TypeScript's static type checking for the event object. While this approach resolves the compilation error, it's generally not recommended as it bypasses TypeScript's benefits in terms of type safety.

Now you maintain TypeScript's type safety for the event object while handling the click event

```
import React from 'react';

const MyButton = () => {
  const handleClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    console.log(e);
  };

  return <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>;
};

export default MyButton;
```

Comment: Answers with no explanation are rarely useful and therefore commonly downvoted. Also, in this case, you've merely changed the type to explicitly `any` rather than implicitly `any`, which I don't believe was the question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey juste time to test the code,

Comment: Next time, don't post the answer until it's complete and you can save time...

Comment: But TypeScript can correctly infer the type of the `onClick` property so the `e` param should not be implicitly `any`. If I do `<button onClick={e => ...}>Click me</button>` I'm not getting the same error, because the `e` is not `any` even if I don't explicitly type it.